# How to convert SVG text to SVG paths?

Tags: java, pdf, svg, converters

I have SVG file (created by com.spire.pdf) and this SVG created from pdf file (pdf file created from html using iText lib).

So i need to convert this SVG to SVG with another tags(path), or SVG to PDF.

All tags in my example is like this: `<text style="fill:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;" font-size="10" x="36" y="46.21002" letter-spacing="-0.075">2020</text>`

I'm find lib, where it's possible to convert (inkscape) where i can by this paramether  `--export-text-to-path` made my SVG file unable to select text.

The final goal i`m need PDF file where unposible to select text from there. (like it was created from image).

There is ways to convert SVG "text" file to SVG "image" file or to pdf?

Inkscape not good for me as i want to do it in java code (Spring boot app)

Comment: "The final goal i`m need PDF file where unposible to select text from there." Does the text have to remain vector? If not, then you could convert the HTML or PDF to an image. Also, why is making the text not selectable important? OCR can be used later on to get most of the text back.

Comment: @Ryan i tryed to use image (png or jpg), but after zoom there is a pixels, and size of file much bigger that i need. So SVG for this situation is the best way. "why is making the text not selectable important" - I want to use this file for some parsing services, such as Sovren, that parsing the file and retrieve information from there. In the end, I will add another invisible layer of information that is selectable. Example of such file you can find here: [docdro.id/qphnWF8]

Comment: @Ryan mostly parsing tools just take selectable text from file and parse this text. So i want to make my files better for parsing by this tools. If i leave just html text or SVG text tags, the structure of resume is bad for parsing by this external services, so solution with 2 layers work the best for now.

Comment: "use this file for some parsing services, such as Sovren, that parsing the file and retrieve information from there." So wouldn't you want to keep the text? What other formats do they accept? PDF? JSON? XML? "so solution with 2 layers work the best for now." This is SVG with invisible text?

Comment: @Ryan nope, SVG created by <path> or image (png or jpeg) is visible layer, and all text from this layer should to be non-selectable. Invisable layer it's just html code (by default is selectable in pdf). In example above just do CTRL + A and you will see that SVG layer you cant copy, and invisable layer can. One more link here:[https://www.docdroid.net/qphnWF8/resumedefaulttemplatewithsvgandatsdata.pdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I’m find only one lib where it's possible to do: inkscape with --export-text-to-path param.

Inkscape work in few threads, and can be runned from java. Convertions are slow, and size of exported files depends of version of inkscape.